# Dynamic partition with Sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hcatalog

From the sqoop documention ,It says Sqoop can be used to import data to Hive with dynamic partition.But couldn't find any example for it. Has anyone tried it.

The Sqoop HCatalog feature supports the following table types:

1. Unpartitioned tables
2. Partitioned tables with a static partitioning key specified
3. Partitioned tables with dynamic partition keys from the  database    result set
4. Partitioned tables with a combination of a static key and    additional dynamic partitioning keys

I'm looking for option # 3.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Sqoop documentation is lagging. It's common in the Hadoop ecosystem to have features introduced in version X and documented in version X+1.

On the other hand, it's a HCatalog feature exposed into Sqoop, so why don't you check the HCatalog documentation under entry "[Dynamic Partitioning](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+DynamicPartitions)" ?
;-)

Comment: I was looking for importing data from Oracle to partitioned  Hive table  using Sqoop (Dynamic partition). I couldn't find it in the mentioned link. :(

Comment: On one side, Sqoop imports data from Oracle in a (crudely) distributed fashion, based on (guesswork on) PK ranges. On the other side, Sqoop pushes each batch to Hive - but it is **Hive** that takes care of dispatching records in the appropriate partition, not Sqoop. Bottom line: configure each side separately.